# How to avoid spaces with stdout in python?

Tags: python, stdout

While messing around with Python, I decided to make a random symbol generator, that would output a continuous stream of characters to the CL.

It's pretty simple, and looks like this:

```
from random import choice
import sys

char_ranges = [[33,48],[58,65],[91,97],[123,127]]

chars = []
for r in char_ranges:
    for i in range(r[0],r[1]):
        chars.append(chr(i))

while True:
    print choice(chars),
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The only problem with it, is that the `,` used after printing a character causes a space to be added after `stdout.flush()` is called.

The way I'd usually get around this, is by concatenating a string and printing that instead, but in this case I want a continuous output flow, and therefore concatenation won't help.

So how can I get a continuous output flow in Python with no spaces?

Answer (score 6):

Use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`.

`print` is a higher level construct for quick and dirty output. If you need more control, use something else.

Comment: The print *statement* can't do it; the print *function* can, though (print("a", end='')).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sys.stdout.write(choice(chars))
```